# firefox CSS transition bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, css-transitions

I wrote some CSS to cause a sidebar to do a slide transition from off the page to visible when you mouse over the side of the page. The CSS is simple and involves adding/removing a class that controls the `left:` position of the sidebar.

```
#sidebarInner{
  height:100%;
  width:50px;
  background-color:blue;
  position: fixed;
  -moz-transition: left .2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: left .2s linear;
  -o-transition: left .2s linear;
  transition: left .2s linear;
  z-index:2;
}
.slideLeft {
  left: -100px;
}
```

Try the following demo on a webkit browser and on Firefox:
http://jsfiddle.net/MmFnY/7/

You'll notice on webkit, the blue colored div has the 0.2s slide left transition but on Firefox it does not. Does anyone know whats wrong with the CSS above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the transition to work you need to provide it with a default left value. Easiest way to do this is probably to give it another class for when it's inside such as:

```
.slideRight{
    left: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MmFnY/19/